# Serial.print only showing "0"

Tags: arduino-uno

This is my code for a timer. My goal is to increment the `count` at every 1 sec.

```
unsigned int count = 0;
int wait = 1000;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{
  long current = millis();
  if((millis() - current) == wait)
  {
    count++;
  }
  Serial.println(count);
}
```

but the serial monitor is only showing zeroes. what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`millis() - current` will always be `0` because `current` is always set to the value of `millis()` right before you compare it.  So it will never equal `wait` (0 is not 1000), so `count` never increments.

Comment: then what can i do to make it better?

Comment: Program it with the correct logic. Think about what you are trying to program logically.

Comment: There is one problem. the `Serial.println(count);` line only working fine inside the `If` statement but when the `Serial.println(count);` line is placed outside of the `if` statement it is only showing zeroes. why is that?

Comment: I told you why in my answer. You are subtracting "now" with "now" and expecting it to be something other than 0. "x - x = 0" and can never be anything else, otherwise maths is broken and the universe will end. You need to compare "now" with **"then"**.